# REGEX to get flags from console command?

Tags: java, regex, console, flags

I'm trying to get a regex that can pull out the flags and values in string. Basically, I need to be able to take a string like this:

```
 command -aparam -b"Another \"quoted\" param" -canother one here
```

And capture the data:

```
a  param
b  Another "quoted" param
c  another one here
```

Here is my Java regex so far:

```
(?<= -\w)(?:(?=")(?:(?:")([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)(?="))|.*?( -\w|$))?
```

But is doesn't quite work yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it would be easier for you if you just split by spaces and checked with what the string begins. If you will add another option in the future it will be a bit difficult I think...

Comment: Well, that's the trick. It can't look for particular "options," it has to find any -\w followed by a value and get the flag and the value.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion is to use one of available CLI parsers. For example [CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) from Jakarta or, better, [args4j](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/05/parsing_command.html).

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I am looking for. I'd really just like to have a regex for this.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize the string into command and its parameters using `split` method,

```
String input = "command -aparam -b\"Another \"quoted\" param\" -canother one here ";
String[] cmds = input.split("\\s*-(?=\\w)");
```